# Find matching value or round up in case number is higher then closest value

Tags: php, arrays, function, math

I'm trying to implement function where user enters a number to the application, for example 101.
Based on this number, function should loop through an array and find matching value. If not found, it should find closest values and round up to higher one. I'm not sure how to explain this properly, but here is an example:

Array consists numbers 100, 150, 200.

• User enters number **101**. No exact number was found, function should return value **150**.

• User enters number **151**. No exact number was found, function should return value **200**.

• User enters number **150**. Exact number was found, function should return value **150**.

I've made a function which finds matching or closest value, but this isn't quite what I want, because it doesn't round the number up, in case exact match wasn't found.

```
$arr(100, 150, 200)
$search = 101;

function getClosest($search, $arr) {
$closest = null;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
     $closest = $item;
  }
}
return $closest;
}
```

In this case it returns the closest number to 101, which is **100**. I would like it to return **150**. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could use `array_search()` or `in_array()` to find exact matches as a first step, then if that doesn't return a match, step through the array for the next-highest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Sort the array first so you can get the next highest value.

```
  <?php
$array = array(100,150,200);
$number = 101;
echo closest($array, $number);
function closest($array, $number) {

    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a >= $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array); // or return NULL;
}
?>
```